# VBA Error Upon updating Worksheet in active Workbook from identical Worksheet in other Workbook

Tags: database, vba

A VBA-newby is in need of help.

I am trying to enable users of my Project to update their Excel-file from another, identical file. The data can include every type of data, including links.

However, I run into two Problems:

**(1) When reaching a certain cell including a link to an external file, I get a Runtime Error 13: Type Mismatch.**

[image]

**(2) At some points in my table, the header gets copied down, in others not.**

[image]

I am relatively new to VBA and don't know where my mistakes are. Any help to reach my Goal would be greatly appreciated!

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wbInput As Workbook
Dim wbOutput As Workbook
Set wbOutput = ActiveWorkbook
Dim wsOutputDB As Worksheet
Set wsOutputDB = wbOutput.Worksheets("Meta DB")
Dim wsOutputCriteria As Worksheet
Set wsOutputCriteria = wbOutput.Worksheets("Criteria")
Dim wsOutputSkills As Worksheet
Set wsOutputSkills = wbOutput.Worksheets("Supplier Skills")


Dim strInput As String
Dim ID As Range
Dim IDcolumn As Range
Dim FindID As Range
Dim FindChange
Dim lRowInput As Integer
Dim lRowOutput As Integer
Dim NextRow As Integer
Dim lastcol As Integer
Dim lastcolOutput As Integer
Dim HeaderColumn As Range
Dim FindNewColItem As Range


strInput = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Set wbInput = Workbooks.Open(strInput)

wbInput.Worksheets("Meta DB").Visible = True

lRowInput = wbInput.Worksheets("Meta DB").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
lRowOutput = wsOutputDB.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
NextRow = wsOutputDB.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1

'1.0. - - ######################Copy all missing DB-Entries####################
With wbInput.Worksheets("Meta DB")

    lastcol = .Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    LastColLetter = Split(wbInput.Worksheets("Meta DB").Cells(3, lastcol).Address, "$")(1)
    lastcolOutput = wsOutputDB.Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    '1.1. - - Check if any new Variables have been added
    For Each HeaderColumn In .Range("B3:" & LastColLetter & "3")

        Set FindNewColItem = wsOutputDB.Range("B3:" & LastColLetter & "3").Find(What:=HeaderColumn, LookAt:=xlWhole)

        If FindNewColItem Is Nothing Then

            NewColLetter = Split(HeaderColumn.Address, "$")(1)

            NextCol = lastcolOutput + 1

            wbInput.Worksheets("Meta DB").Range(NewColLetter & "3").Copy Destination:=wsOutputDB.Range(NewColLetter & "3")

            NextCol = NextCol + 1

        End If

    Next HeaderColumn


    '1.2. - - Check if there are any new Entries to the Database
    For Each ID In .Range("D4:D" & lRowInput)

        Set FindID = wsOutputDB.Range("D4:D" & lRowOutput).Find(What:=ID, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

        '1.2.1. - - If ID is a new Entry, simply add it to our file, else...
        If FindID Is Nothing Then

            NewIDrow = Split(ID.Address, "$")(2)

            wbInput.Worksheets("Meta DB").Range("B" & NewIDrow & ":" & LastColLetter & NewIDrow).Copy Destination:=wsOutputDB.Range("B" & NextRow & ":" & LastColLetter & NextRow)

            NextRow = NextRow + 1

        Else
        '1.2.2. - - If ID already exists, check for Updates of any Information

            For Each IDcolumn In .Range("B" & ID.row & ":" & LastColLetter & ID.row)

                Set FindChange = wsOutputDB.Range("B" & FindID.row & ":" & LastColLetter & FindID.row).Find(What:=IDcolumn)

                If FindChange Is Nothing Then

                    ColLetter = Split(IDcolumn.Address, "$")(1)

                    wbInput.Worksheets("Meta DB").Range(ColLetter & ID.row).Copy Destination:=wsOutputDB.Range(ColLetter & FindID.row)

                End If

            Next IDcolumn

        End If

    Next ID

End With
```

Comment: add minimal data example that reproduces the error